# How to write into a python driven config file from another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 python files. One is my main file mainFile.py and another file is basically a configuration file config.py

Structure of the config.py

```
class Configurations(object):
    CONFIGURE_VM = True
    CPU_CORES = 2
    RAM = 96
    THREADS = 2
```

This is how I am reading values of the config.py in my mainFile.py:-

```
from config import Configurations

def writeValues():
    vm_configure = Configurations.CONFIGURE_VM
    vcpu = Configurations.CPU_CORES
    memory = Configurations.RAM
```

In my mainFile.py, I need to write the code to change the values of all the above parameters so that they can become something like:-

```
class Configurations(object):
    CONFIGURE_VM = False
    CPU_CORES = 1
    RAM = 32
```

The use case is to read new values from the config.py everytime the mainFile.py runs and write new values in it.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried writing to a file? Python code is just text...

Comment: Better yet, use one of the many available serialization packages. INI files, XML files, JSON files, pickle files, etc. are all probably better ways of doing this. That being said, I've definitely used Python code as config files. My recommendation would be to stay away from the class. Just dynamically load a module that looks a lot like an INI file.

Comment: I personally use xmls/jsons/pickle files or even plain text files as configuration files myself. But sadly, this is an existing code I have to work upon and I am not in a position to make architectural changes into it at the moment. Hence, I am seeking for some help in this. @MadPhysicist

Comment: Maybe the easier way is to update the `config.py` itself with the new values? Or do you mean you don't even have write access to the `config.py`?

Comment: I have the write access to the config.py. I need to write the updated values to the existing config.py everytime mainFile.py runs. @r.ook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my own problem by using python FileInput library.

```
def writeValues(filename, input, output):
cwd = os.getcwd()
filename = os.path.join(cwd[:cwd.find('home')], 'home', 'config', filename)
for line in fileinput.input([filename], inplace=True):
    line = line.strip("\n").split("=")
    if input in line[0]:
        line[1] = " " + str(output)
    line = '='.join(line)
    print(line)
```